# HR-ABAP: how limit values in select-options list

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary, sap-hr

When I want to get a list of users absence types, I use:

```
select-options: abs for p2001-awart.
```

When I want to get a list of users presence types, I use:

```
select-options: prs for p2002-awart.
```

In both cases I get a list that contains all types together (absences and presences).

I know that t554s-art01 = 'A' for absences,   t554s-art01 = 'P' for presences.

Can I get not mixed lists after F4? Maybe anybody know how to set some condition " select-options with where" in initialization block or in process on value request?

Thank you

Comment: To clarify the question, it's important to say that `p2001-awart` is linked to the search help `h_t554s` (and less importantly, has foreign key check with table `t554s`) and it's not filtering. I don't see a standard solution filtering `t554s-art01`, so a custom one can be developed, but there are many ways. The question implies many different answers which is against Stack Overflow philosophy. That would be great if you generalize the question instead of limiting to SAP HR, and targeted to adapting any standard search help.

Comment: So my global goal is to create ABAP-HR program similar to RPTABS00, but with out using PNP logical database. Why? Because PNP gives the same f4 popup list  for absences field and presences field.       i need different  text values for abs. And pres. fields from t554t depending from t554t-art01. So F4 popups for awart is program RPTABS29 that is included in RPTABS00. Some months ago i didn't know that , so i created my own function module for this purpose.

Comment: Now i stuck on a liitle with the condition to select right time values from time data values. If you are interested in right f4 popups, write me : olmar-anari@ukr.net I will share that piece of code .maybe it's sh*t for abap experts. But it may be helpful for newbies like i am yet)))